# Windows API: UpdateLayeredWindow return values

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, splash-screen, layered-windows

I have a layered window in my program and it seems(visually) to work fine, but the return code from `UpdateLayeredWindow` is supposed to be a non-zero value on success. In my case, it is 0, and `GetLastError` returns 87, that is for an incorrect parameter. Can someone please tell me if there is anything wrong with my setup? Here is the complete function, window styles are `WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOPMOST` and `WS_POPUP`.

```
bool SplashScreen(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE m_hinstance)
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(m_hinstance, "splash.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 640, 640, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
    HDC             hdc;
    BITMAP          bitmap;
    HDC             hdcMem;
    HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;
    int result=0;

    if(!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, (255 * 100) / 100, LWA_ALPHA))
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error SetLayeredWindowAttributes: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    if(!hdc)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error BeginPaint: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if(!hdcMem)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error CreateCompatibleDC: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
    result=BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 640, 640, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    if(result==0)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error BitBlt: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
    blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    result=UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd,GetDC(NULL),NULL,NULL,hdcMem,NULL, RGB(0,0,0),&blend, ULW_ALPHA);// Returns non-zero on success(!), in reality works when 0 is returned.
    if(result==0)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error UpdateLayeredWindow: %d",GetLastError());// Error UpdateLayeredWindow: 87
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    result=SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255,255,255), 0, ULW_COLORKEY);
    if(result==0)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error SetLayeredWindowAttributes: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    result=EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    if(result==0)
    {
        char msg[255];
        sprintf(msg,"Error EndPaint: %d",GetLastError());
        MessageBox(hwnd,msg,"System",MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdc);
    DeleteObject(hdcMem);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` and `UpdateLayeredWindow()` on the same HWND.  That will not work, and the documentation is very clear on that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540(v=vs.85).aspx

> Note that once SetLayeredWindowAttributes has been called for a layered window, subsequent UpdateLayeredWindow calls will fail until the layering style bit is cleared and set again.

Do not use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` and `UpdateLayeredWindow()` together.  They are very different methodologies.  Either use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` with traditional `WM_PAINT` drawing, or use `UpdateLayeredWindow()` with an in-memory bitmap.  Do not use both.  Based on what you have shown, you should be using `UpdateLayeredWindow()` by itself.  It will set a bitmap as the window contents and set the window's transparency/alpha at the same time.

And do not use `Begin/EndPaint()` outside of a `WM_PAINT` handler.